# How to Modify UITableView Data Source Array Properly

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsmutablearray

Say I would like to remove rows or add rows to a table. Is it smarter for me to modify the data source and let the table do updates or use UITableView's insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation: and deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation: selectors? Whenever I try to modify the actual data source array, whose size is also used to determine in the the data source's tableView:numberOfCellsInSection: protocol method, I am thrown an error saying that the table must have the same number of cells per section before and after a table update. The data source array itself is an NSMutableArray; does this array get automatically updated when I use the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths and insertRowsAtIndexPaths selectors? I would assume not. But how do I add or remove rows while also updating the data source array?

Comment: The behavior of `NSMutableArray` has nothing to do with autorelease or copy. But if you're not sure, you could always check [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectAtIndex:): *To fill the gap, all elements beyond index are moved by subtracting 1 from their index.*

Comment: @Caleb quite frankly I posted this as a question because no decent documentation appeared on a general stackoverflow or google search. I have found it rather inefficient to take the "try it myself" approach every time I encounter a programmatical issue. In fact, I got my answer within moments while I paused and continued work on something else

Comment: @Savagewood as per Caleb's link, in this case the answer is given clearly in Apple's official documentation, which is available directly in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy My derpiness for not finding that as easily. As for copy and atomic attributes, they do indeed affect the state of a property during retrieval in respect to when they are set to different values when working with multithreading. I revised my question to be more specific to the exact issue I was trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

```
NSMutableArray* array = @["a", "b", "c"]

NSLog(@"%@", array[1])
// prints "b"

[array removeObjectAtIndex:1] 
// ["a", "c"]

NSLog(@"%@", array[1])
// now prints "c".
```

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific. Mind taking another look?